# Control the version constraint for dotnet pack project references

Tags: .net, package, nuget, .net-core

When I'm using dotnet pack to create nuget packages, it creates package dependencies for project references.

It seems to always create these with the constraint being "greater than or equal to the current project version"

Is there any way to control the version constraint that dotnet pack produces?

I'm using VS2017 and csproj files for netstandard1.6;net461 projects.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to work for PackageReference in csproj using the range syntax `[1.0.1,2)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files
but isn't yet supported for ProjectReference (that I have been able to find).

You could split your projects out so that they build seperately and use PackageReference instead, but thats not a great workaround if you have many projects that are all chained together.

Comment: Yeah, this was my conclusion. Seems like the whole infrastructure is geared towards packaging everything separately, which isn't really practical for me right now. Hopefully they'll add this feature soon