# NuGet package has a dependency resolved to highest version

Tags: .net, nuget

I develop a library that use the NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore that is compatible with all versions 3.1.

I would like when my library is restored it also restores the highest valid version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, currently the 3.1.22.

I try with to add in the csproj :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="[3.1, 3.2)" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But after packaged with `dotnet pack` and added to other project, this restore the lowest valid version `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0`.

Also I try with :

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.*" />
```

But the package generated (with `dotnet pack`) has the dependency the **CURRENT** highest valid version. See the generated nuspec is :

```xml
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
    <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="3.1.22" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

Two problems with this :

- The package isn't compatible with precedent version (like 3.1.13).
- When Entity Framework Core 3.1.23 will be released, the 3.1.22 will be restored.

EDIT :
I use NuGet Version: 5.0.2.5988 and .NET SDK 5.0.403.

Comment: Can you post your entire `.csproj`?

Comment: This looks like the same problem you're facing, but in 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725439/control-the-version-constraint-for-dotnet-pack-project-references

Comment: Please tell us exactly what version of NuGet you're using (and/or exact version of VS too)

Comment: @Dai - I added the full csproj and information about tools.

Comment: @Dai - I don't fully understand the linked question, but I don't think it's similar.

Comment: This [old github issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1192) is similar to my question. It does not seem possible to resolve the highest version of third-party dependency of a NuGet package.